# Why "Game Center" button not showing up in iTunes connect?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

In https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf it says:

> Clicking on the "Manage Game Center"￼ button on your App Summary Page
>   allows you to enable your app for Game Center testing, and set up your
>   Leaderboard and Achievement data.

But when I go to my iTunes connect there is no such button.

I am in the end of my first app development and want to write the Game Center code, but I can't, since there is no button to register my app into iTunesConnect.

Do I have to submit and release to the app store first, and after the first release is published integrate the Game Center into the first update? How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doesn't need to upload the app. Just fill the info (including icons, and snapshots. You can change it later, don't worry). Then, when all the info is filled, you have your app info page. In this page you can access to iAds stuff, game center stuff and many more.

But no, you DON'T have to upload nothing more than images LOL!